# Return child of a child related table (TaskList > TaskListItem > Vehicle)

Tags: knex.js, bookshelf.js

Considering the model below, I need to return all `TaskLists` with their `TaskListItems` (1-N) and the last one with its respective `Vehicle` (N-1, a vehicle can have one or many `TaskListItems`, but a `TaskListItem` cannot exist without a vehicle).

TaskList

```
let bookshelf = require('./base');

var TaskList,
    TaskLists;

TaskList = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'tasklists',
    createdByUser: function () {
        return this.belongsTo('User', 'createdBy');
    },
    resources: function() {
        return this.belongsToMany('User', 'tasklist_resources', 'tasklistId', 'userId', 'id');
    },
    items: function() {
        return this.hasMany('TaskListItem', 'tasklistId');
    },
    status: function () {
        return this.belongsTo('StatusTaskList', 'statusId');
    }
});

TaskLists = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
    model: TaskList
});

module.exports = {
    TaskList: bookshelf.model('TaskList', TaskList),
    TaskLists: bookshelf.collection('TaskLists', TaskLists)
};
```

TaskListItem

```
let bookshelf = require('./base');

var TaskListItem,
    TaskListItems;

TaskListItem = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'tasklist_items',
    createdByUser: function () {
        return this.belongsTo('User', 'createdBy');
    },
    vehicle: function() {
        return this.belongsTo('Vehicle', 'vehicleId').through('VehicleAnomaly', 'vehicleAnomalyId', 'vehicleId', 'id');
    }
});

TaskListItems = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
    model: TaskListItem
});

module.exports = {
    TaskListItem: bookshelf.model('TaskListItem', TaskListItem),
    TaskListItems: bookshelf.collection('TaskListItems', TaskListItems)
};
```

Vehicle

```
let bookshelf = require('./base');

var Vehicle,
    Vehicles;

Vehicle = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'vehicles'
});

Vehicles = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
    model: Vehicle
});

module.exports = {
    Vehicle: bookshelf.model('Vehicle', Vehicle),
    Vehicles: bookshelf.collection('Vehicles', Vehicles)
};
```

I've been able to return all `TaskLists` with its `TaskListItems`, but I don't know how to add a third level to the result.

```
new TaskList()
            .query(qb => {
                qb.join('tasklist_items', 'tasklists.id', '=', 'tasklist_items.tasklistId');
                qb.where('tasklist_items.statusId', '=', 1);
            })
            .fetchAll({
                withRelated: [ {
                    'items': function(qb) {
                        qb.where('statusId', '=', 1);
                    }
                }]
            })
```

How can I return the `TaskLists`, their `TaskListItems` along with each `Vehicle` of a `TaskListItem`?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer. I'm sharing in case someone else ever needs this:

```
new TaskList()
            .query(qb => {
                qb.join('tasklist_items', 'tasklists.id', '=', 'tasklist_items.tasklistId');
                qb.where('tasklist_items.statusId', '=', 1);
            })
            .fetchAll({
                withRelated: [ {
                    'items': function(qb) {
                        qb.where('statusId', '=', 1);
                    },
                    'items.vehicle': function(qb) {
                        qb.orderBy('location', 'ASC');
                    }
                }]
            })
```

The solution is to add a new item in the `withRelated` array, pointing to the child model (`vehicle`) of another child model.